# Activity indicator displayed randomly on collection view cell after scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiactivityindicatorview

I have dynamic number of custom collection view cells. Each cell has download button and on click of download button I have added activity indicator in place of download button and it will get animated till image will get download. But if I scroll collection view after clicking of download button then activity indicator is displayed on any random cell.

Comment: perhaps adding your code may be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is related to the fact then cell are `reused`.

If you manually add the AcitivityIndicator, you must manually remove it.

You have to do it in 2 places:

- In the completion block of your download method ( if the download completes while the cell is displayed )
- In the `prepareForReuse` function of you `UITableViewCell` class.